# How to calculate values in two arrays in Python under a single constraint?

Tags: python, arrays

So I have been trying to study Python for a little while now (roughly 2 months) and while I have the basics down, I am trying some more challenging scenarios from HackerRank.com. I feel like I am somewhat close to the answer here, because I feel like the ask here is fairly simple.

I know that the values need to be setup so that n (number of keyboards) and m (number of drives) do not go over b (budget), but comes as close to that number as possible.

If it is not possible to be less than or equal to b, then I need to print a -1 instead.

The order of the arguments is b (budget), n (keyboards), m (drives). The next line of input is the prices of the keyboards, and the last line of input is the prices of drives.

For example:

Sample input:

```
10 2 3
3 1
5 2 8
```

Sample output:

```
9
```

Here is the code so far:

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
import sys

#
# Complete the getMoneySpent function below.
#
def getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b):
    
    keyboards = int(keyboards * n)
    drives = int(drives * m)
    if keyboards + drives > b:
        return -1
    else:
        return keyboards + drives
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    bnm = input().split()

    b = int(bnm[0])

    n = int(bnm[1])

    m = int(bnm[2])

    keyboards = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    drives = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    #
    # The maximum amount of money she can spend on a keyboard and USB drive, or -1 if she can't purchase both items
    #

    moneySpent = getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b)

    fptr.write(str(moneySpent) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

As it is, I get an error stating:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 39, in <module>
    moneySpent = getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b)
  File "Solution.py", line 11, in getMoneySpent
    keyboards = int(keyboards * n)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: The exception message gives you a clue. There's something wrong in the way you are using `int()`. It appears to be getting a `list` instead of what it expects (a string, bytes-like object or a number). The first parameter of your `getMoneySpent()` function is a list. A `*` is a valid operation on a list and will in turn return a list.

Comment: Inside `getMoneySpent` replace the first line with `keyboards = sum(keyboards) * n` and the same for the next line